# GitHub throws me to not found page whenever i create a new organization

Tags: github

Lately i have been having a problem with github.

after i create a new public organization, for instance: "myorg", i get an 404 error when trying to access it (https://github.com/myorg)

The only way i can access the organization is through the dashboard (https://github.com/orgs/myorg/dashboard)

But then i still can't access any repositories that i create in that organization.

All my other organizations i can access easily via https://github.com/myorg
and repositories via https://github.com/myorg/myrepo
but it's not the case with new organizations.

Am i doing something wrong?
Please help me solve it.

Thanks,
Arik

Comment: You might want to contact GitHub about that so that they can fix if there's some issue on their end

Comment: Some login issue perhaps? (https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/14#issuecomment-14500708) or some webhook (http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/132-github-repository-gives-404), or an authorization  to revoke and add again: http://help.appveyor.com/discussions/problems/142-unable-to-create-a-project-from-github-org-account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can access `https://github.com/orgs/myorg/dashboard`, you should be able to access the organization page on `https://github.com/myorg`.

However if you cannot access the organization page, contact [GitHub Support](https://github.com/c) and describe the problem you have.